# VuePress: how to import css framework (basscss)

Tags: webpack, vuepress

I'm trying to use [basscss](https://basscss.com) with a [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) project and am unsure how to properly include the basscss files without referring directly to the file in mode_modules and would like to avoid using a third party CDN.

So far, I've installed basscss with yarn and a few postcss plugins and made my own theme:

```
.vuepress
├── node_modules
├── package.json
└── theme
    ├── Layout.vue
    └── styles
        └── theme.styl
```

In my `config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  postcss: {
    plugins: [
      require('postcss-import')
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

In `Layout.vue`: `<style src="./styles/theme.styl" lang="stylus"></style>`

In `theme.style`, `@import "basscss.css"` which results in the error:

> Module build failed (from
>   /Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
>   Error: Failed to find 'basscss.css'   in [
>       /Users/user/code/project_title/.vuepress/theme/styles   ]

It's quite easy to do with a standard `vue-cli` webpack template, but I'm struggling with VuePress as I'm not too familiar with how webpack is functioning in this particular case.

Comment: What version of vuepress and basscss are you using?